Is it possible to convert a Boolean Formula to "negative normal form" in polynomial time?
A Boolean formula using only negation $\neg$, AND $\land$ and OR $\lor$ is said
to be in negative normal form if the negation only appears in front of a variable, like this $\neg(x)$.
So for instance, the Boolean function
$$f(x,y) = \neg(x \land y)$$
is not in negative normal form, but we have
$$f(x,y) = \neg(x) \lor \neg(y)$$
for all possible inputs $x,y$.
Question. Is it possible to bring any Boolean function into negative normal form in
polynomial time?

If the boolean formula is in infix notation, e.g. like Scheme programming language, we can convert $f=\neg(\neg f)$ by recursive applying De Morgan laws in $\neg f$.

The following algorithm has a complexity linear (hence polynomial) in the size of the boolean formula:
NNF(f):
   match f with:
      | x → x
      | ¬x → ¬x
      | g∨h → NNF(g)∨NNF(h)
      | g∧h → NNF(g)∧NNF(h)
      | ¬¬g → NNF(g)
      | ¬(g∨h) → NNF(¬g)∧NNF(¬h)
      | ¬(g∧h) → NNF(¬g)∨NNF(¬h)

